# How to force Nginx Ingress controller to respond HTTP 426 to deprecated routes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have the following ingress for my namespace on Kubernetes with paths */api/1.0/* redirecting to my old-service and the rest redirecting to the new.
Before deprecating & deleting my old-service I would like Nginx to respond with an HTTP 426 redirect error code only on the */api/1.0/* paths.

How can I do this ?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: xxx-ingress
  namespace: xxx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream: "error timeout http_502 non_idempotent"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-pass-headers: "Content-Length"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.xxx.com
    - www.xxxcom
    secretName: xxx-ingress-tls
  rules:
    - host: api.xxx.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/1.0/users/password/reset/token
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: old-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/1.0/users/login
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: old-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/1.0/users/request_migration_sync
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: old-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/1.0/users/migrate
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: old-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: new-service
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: www.xxx.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: new-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Hi Victor R welcome to S.F. All `Ingress` objects are unioned together, so create a 2nd `Ingress` with just that `path:` and then use [`configuration-snippet:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) to do whatever crazy nginx-y things you want when that path matches